# Java - Calling the constructor of a superclass fails

Tags: java, constructor, subclass, superclass

Here is a basic class I have set up to calculate earnings with stocks.
Focus on the "Stock" constructor here:

```
public class Stock{
    private String symbol;
    private int totalShares;
    private double totalCost;

    public void Stock(String symbol){
        this.symbol = symbol;
        totalShares = 0;
        totalCost = 0.0;
    }

    public double getProfit(double currentPrice){
        double marketValue = totalShares * currentPrice;
        return marketValue - totalCost;
    }

    public void purchase(int shares, double pricePerShare){
        totalShares += shares;
        totalCost += shares*pricePerShare;
    }

    public int getTotalShares(){
        return totalShares;
    }
}
```

I have created a subclass called DividendStock, which is supposed to calculate dividend earnings.

```
public class DividendStock extends Stock{
    private double dividends;

    public DividendStock(String symbol){
        super(symbol);
        dividends = 0.0;
    }

    public void payDividend(double amountPerShare){
        dividends += amountPerShare*getTotalShares();
    }
}
```

The constructor of this class doesnt allow me to call the superclass's constuctor:  super(symbol);
The error message is as goes: "constructor Stock in class Stock cannot be applied to given types;"

I have searched for a solution, but everything seems to be in place.
Any ideas of why it doesnt allow me to call this constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A constructor does not have any return type. When you put the return type it will be a normal method.

```
public void Stock(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
    totalShares = 0;
    totalCost = 0.0;
}
```

Should be

```
public Stock(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
    totalShares = 0;
    totalCost = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you se much!! I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

Replace it `public void Stock(String symbol){ this.symbol = symbol; totalShares = 0; totalCost = 0.0; }`

To `public Stock(String symbol){ this.symbol = symbol; totalShares = 0; totalCost = 0.0; }`